# How to prove that multiplicative group of integers modulo n contains only integers coprime to n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have this question given as exercise in my discrete math book. Since $(\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^\times$ is a group, every element of it has an inverse. So, how to prove that all those integers are coprime to n?

Comment: Start by assuming that $n=\prod{p_i}^{k^i}$ for $p_i$ prime, and assume $k$ is *not* relatively prime to $n$.  Can you prove that $k$ must then be a zero divisor?

Comment: @RobertShore if $k$ is not relatively prime to $n$, then $k$ can be written as a production of some $p_i$ from your equation and the rest of them are equal to some $m$ and $(k\times m)\equiv 0\pmod n$, hence $k$ is zero divisor, right? But I can't figure out what contradiction we get out of this.

Comment: Suppose that $\gcd(k,n)=d\neq 1$. So, $(k,n)=(dK,dN)$ with $\gcd(K,N)=1$. Then, if $k$ has an inverse $k'$ modulo $n$, then $kk'\equiv 1\pmod n$ implying $dKk'\equiv 1\pmod{dN}$ implying $0\equiv dNKk'\equiv N\pmod{dN=n}$ implying $n\mid N$. Since $n=dN$, we also have $N\mid n$, so $n=N$, thus $dN=N$, so $d=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @learner I can't understand, why $N\equiv 0\pmod n$. Could you explain it?

Comment: We multiplied both sides of $dKk'\equiv 1\pmod{dN}$ by $N$, so $dNKk'\equiv N\pmod{dN}$. Now, note that $n=dN$ obviously divides $dNKk'$ (it's a multiple), ergo $N\equiv dNKk'\equiv 0\pmod{dN=n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you can already prove that any integer that has a nontrivial gcd with $n$ is a zero divisor. But zero divisors are never invertible in any ring. If $k$ is a zero divisor, then by definition $km=0$ with $m\ne0$. But if $k^{-1}$ exists, then $k^{-1}km=k^{-1}0$, or $m=0$, contradiction.